# How many commands does jedis pipline exec one time by default?

Tags: java, redis, jedis

I was using jedis pipeline to insert batch of data into redis. now I face a confused problem. I want to batch a specific size and then call sync(), but it seems that the pipeline will call sync automatically every 200 records approximately. here are my codes, can anyone tell me if there exists any configurations about this ?

```
public class RedisClusterTest {
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String host = args[0];
    int port = Integer.valueOf(args[1]);
    int cnt = Integer.valueOf(args[2]);
    Jedis jedis = new Jedis(host, port);

    Pipeline pip = jedis.pipelined();
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 2000; i++) {
        pip.hset("Server", String.valueOf(i), String.valueOf(i));
        Thread.sleep(10);
    }
    // When it end loop, about 1900 records has already been insert into redis, and the last sync only made last remaining data been sync.
    pip.sync()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pipeline does not wait for your confirmation to send batch to Redis. Documentation says that:

> Sometimes you need to send a bunch of different commands. A very cool way to do that, and have better performance than doing it the naive way, is to use pipelining. This way you send commands **without waiting for response**, and you actually read the responses at the end, which is faster.

By summing up it says that pipeline is used **without waiting for response** and is just sent like a stream.

I took a look in their source code which confirms their documentation.

```
public Pipeline pipelined() {
  pipeline = new Pipeline();
  pipeline.setClient(client);
  return pipeline;
}
```

This returns your Pipeline instance.
Then you call bunch of HSETs

```
public Long hset(final byte[] key, final byte[] field, final byte[] value) {
  checkIsInMultiOrPipeline();
  client.hset(key, field, value);
  return client.getIntegerReply();
}
```

Which gets reply **rightaway**.

Then you call **sync** which:

> Synchronize pipeline by reading all responses. This operation close the pipeline. In order to get return values from pipelined commands, capture the different Response<?> of the commands you execute.

In other words it handles your pipeline instance.

By summing up, you should not use "pipelined" if you expect from it to send a batch only when you call sync. It is not how it works.

Comment: Great explanation. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on Jedis **4.3.1** (the newest at the time of writing this response)

Yes, you can configure this behavior.

Basically all commands (in [Redis serialization protocol](https://redis.io/docs/reference/protocol-spec/) form) are added to the internal buffer. The default size of the buffer is **8192** bytes.
When you pipeline commands, the buffer can be too small to store all the commands. In such case, commands from the buffer are automatically flushed and sent to the server, to free space for your next commands.
You noticed that commands were flushed every ~200 commands, so in your case this happened multiple times.

The size of the buffer can be modified by setting System property: **jedis.bufferSize.output**.

Set buffer big enough to store all your commands. Just remember that different commands have different lengths.
If you have the buffer big enough, all the commands will be sent when **Pipeline.sync()** is called.